# Is it possible to mimic tabs and have the names of tabs generated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Website is here http://www17.myfantasyleague.com/2013/home/78896

Notice along the left hand side there are tabs going vertically..."Home,Management,Game Day....ect"

The webhost of this site, allows us as end users to create css, html and js to add on to their existing design. The tabs are generated and named through a control panel on the site and then displayed on the homepage ONLY , and not on any other page on the site. However, I was able to use this script to show the tabs on all pages of the site. As on this link to same site http://football17.myfantasyleague.com/2013/options?L=78896&O=07 , you see the tabs on left are generated for display via the script below

```
// ADD HOME PAGE TABS TO REPORTS
var myURLBase = "http://%LIVESCORINGHOST%/%YEAR%/home/%LEAGUEID%";
var mimicHomePageTabs = new Array();
mimicHomePageTabs[0]="Home";
mimicHomePageTabs[1]="Management";
mimicHomePageTabs[2]="Game Day";
mimicHomePageTabs[3]="Standings";
mimicHomePageTabs[4]="History";
mimicHomePageTabs[5]="Playoffs";
mimicHomePageTabs[6]="Top Players";
mimicHomePageTabs[7]="Top Free Agents";
mimicHomePageTabs[8]="Pools";

if(!document.getElementById("body_home")||(document.getElementById("body_home")&&location.href.indexOf("MODULE=MESSAGE")!=-1)) {
document.write("<div id='homepagetabsdiv'><ul id='homepagetabs'>\n");
for(var x=0; x<mimicHomePageTabs.length;x++) {
document.write("<li id='tab"+x+"' onclick='window.location.assign(\""+myURLBase+"#"+x+"\")'>"+mimicHomePageTabs[x]+"</li>\n");
}
document.write("</ul></div>\n");
}
```

The only drawback is i have to manually name each tab in the script to match what is added in the control panel they have. My question/job is, to make it so the tabs are shown on all pages, as this script does, but to have those tabs automatically named to match what is being typed into their control panel to generate the tabs to begin with.

Is this even possible without having full control of the website as we do on their severs ?

Comment: By the sounds of things you're wanting persistence, which is usually the result of calling the data from a database using a server-side language.

Comment: Alex your talking above my knowledge lol , do you have an example ?